# Shiro page level access

Tags: permissions, shiro

I'm fairly new to Apache Shiro, but hopefully this is a simple question. I've spent a fair amount of time searching for an answer but can't find one.

I have an admin page as a JSP which I want to display various links based on the user permissions. For example:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="shiro" uri="http://shiro.apache.org/tags" %>

<shiro:hasPermission name="admin:user:update">
   <li class="admin-link update-user">Update Users</li>
</shiro:hasPermission>
<shiro:hasPermission name="admin:role:update">
   <li class="admin-link update-role">Update Roles</li>
</shiro:hasPermission>
```

This works nicely. However, if the user has no permissions for the links on that page, I'd like to display a message. I don't care which link(s) they have rights to, any link would stop the message displaying.

I thought of doing:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="shiro" uri="http://shiro.apache.org/tags" %>
<shiro:hasPermission name="admin">
   <shiro:hasPermission name="admin:user:update">
      <li class="admin-link update-user">Update Users</li>
   </shiro:hasPermission>
   <shiro:hasPermission name="admin:role:update">
      <li class="admin-link update-role">Update Roles</li>
   </shiro:hasPermission>
</shiro:hasPermission>
<shiro:lacksPermission name="admin">
    Sorry, you do not have admin rights
</shiro:lacksPermission>
```

However, I'm using wildcard permissions so having a specific permission like "admin:role:update" does not imply the generic permission like "admin", so the "you do not have admin rights" message always shows.

(That is:
`new WildcardPermission("admin").implies(new WildcardPermission("admin:user:update")` is true but `new WildcardPermission("admin:user:update").implies(new WildcardPermission("admin")` is false)

Is there an easy way to do this, or do I need to define a new permission with "admin page rights" and ensure that any roles which get rights to use any links also need this new permission? (Which sounds like a maintenance hassle).

Answer (score 1):

Use core tag lib inside shiro tags like

```
<c:set var="allowed"  value="false"/>

<shiro:hasPermission name="admin">
   <shiro:hasPermission name="admin:user:update">
      <c:set var="allowed"  value="true"/>
      <li class="admin-link update-user">Update Users</li>
   </shiro:hasPermission>
   <shiro:hasPermission name="admin:role:update">
      <c:set var="allowed"  value="true"/>
      <li class="admin-link update-role">Update Roles</li>
   </shiro:hasPermission>
</shiro:hasPermission>
<c:if test="${not allowed}" >
    Sorry, you do not have admin rights
</c:if>
```